# call the same http request if it fails but with different parameter to get default data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-service

does it make sense to call the same http request call within the catch if the first one fails but with different parameter in order to return some default data ?

```
var defaultData = false;

clientService.getClients(defaultData)
     .then(function (res) {

         //do something

      }).catch(function (err) {

          defaultData = true;

          clientService.getClients(defaultData)
                .then(function (res) {

                 //do something

                }).catch(function (err) {

                    console.log(err)

                });
      });
```

or this is a bad way ?

Comment: If it meets your use case...why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to `return` the new promise to the catch handler. The code will then chain properly and it avoids nesting:

```
clientService.getClients({defaultData:false})
 .catch(function (err) {

    return clientService.getClients({defaultData: true})

}).then(function (res) {

    //return something

}).catch(function (err) {

    console.log(err)
    //IMPORTANT re-throw err
    throw err;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue not bad but I think you have to find reason of the failure and on the furniture do some action.
the best is that you have to create an error handler like:

```
errorHandler(error:any){
  ///.....
}
```

In this method you should check status code of response, for instance if it is 500, you can't call again. or some thing like this.